# SQL - How to sort values in special order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

[image]

For example, I have a table ordered by column "code". Also, I now exact number of rows of my table (6 for this case).
I need to create one more column with rank using next rules:

1. The first value has the first code (1)
2. The second value has the last code (6)
3. The third value has the second code (2)
4. The forth value has penultimate code (5) etc.

How can I create this order? Even if you have just an idea without query, share it with me, please.

Comment: You can use the rownumber() solution proposed below. However if the values for «name» are known by advance you can use a simple hardcoded CASE WHEN... with desired rank for each value. More readable and lighter to execute.

Comment: Another obvious solution would be to add a «sortorder» column in the table. At least you could rely on it everytime you need it in any query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY code ASC) rn1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY code DESC) rn2
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY ABS(rn2 - rn1) DESC, code;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0bd8c186ba4f9502add61ef6b0617bf)**

How it works: two counters based on code, calculate difference so first and last has the same value, when tie prefer code.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to just `order by code`... Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `row_number()` too, but I think the logic you want is more:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(order by code asc ) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(order by code desc) rn_desc
    from tab t
) t
order by case when rn_asc <= rn_desc then rn_asc else rn_desc end, rn_asc;
```

This ranks records in both directions, and then uses the smallest of the two ranks for ordering. The second sorting criteria ensures that the smallest value of the two consistently comes first.